# SQL Update, updating everything in the table

Tags: sql

We are trying to an update on a pricing table, using the following query. When the update part is not included, the results turn back the correct number of records. But when we include the update code, it updates every record within the table.

Where are we going wrong?

```
   UPDATE pricelist 
   SET    plfromdate = '2017-05-01',       -- from date 

   pltodate = '2037-04-30',         -- to date

   plunitprice = plunitprice * 1.09 -- % to be applied
   USE whatifdb
   SELECT          pg.pgmaster pgmast, 
            * 
   FROM            pricelist pl 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN allpartmaster pm 
   ON              pl.plpart = pm.partnum<br> 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN partgroup pg 
   ON              pm.prodgroup = pg.pgcode<br> 
   WHERE           pltype = 'SUN' 
   AND             pgcode NOT IN ('CABMCL', 
                           'CABPOD', 
                           'CABSTDH', 
                           'CABSTD', 
                           'CABSTDI', 
                           'CABTEK') (<br>SELECT DISTINCT pricelistid 
             FROM            customeraddresses<br> 
           WHERE           currencyid = 'STG')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any where clause in your update.
Use the update you have on your select statement.

```
update pl
 set plfromdate = '2017-05-01', -- from date 
 pltodate = '2037-04-30', -- to date
 plunitprice = plunitprice * 1.09 -- % to be applied
from pricelist pl
 left outer join allpartmaster pm on pl.plpart = pm.partnum
 left outer join partgroup pg on pm.prodgroup = pg.pgcode
 where pltype = 'SUN' and pgcode not in ('CABMCL', 'CABPOD', 'CABSTDH', 'CABSTD', 'CABSTDI', 'CABTEK') (
 select distinct pricelistid from customeraddresses
 where currencyid = 'STG')
```